# Why do subpages not load?

Tags: mysql, typo3, typoscript, typo3-extensions

I am learning TYPO3 and created a website with several subpages, but
everytime I click on a Subpage I get this error.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT * FROM `tt_content` WHERE 
(`tt_content`.`pid` IN (19)) AND (`colPos`=Array) AND 
(`tt_content`.`sys_language_uid` = 0) AND ((`tt_content`.`deleted` = 0) AND 
(`tt_content`.`t3ver_state` <= 0) AND (`tt_content`.`pid` <> -1) AND 
(`tt_content`.`hidden` = 0) AND (`tt_content`.`starttime` <= 1540989540) AND 
((`tt_content`.`endtime` = 0) OR (`tt_content`.`endtime` > 1540989540)) AND 
(((`tt_content`.`fe_group` = '') OR (`tt_content`.`fe_group` IS NULL) OR 
(`tt_content`.`fe_group` = '0') OR (FIND_IN_SET('0', 
`tt_content`.`fe_group`)) OR (FIND_IN_SET('-1', `tt_content`.`fe_group`))))) 
ORDER BY `sorting` ASC': Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'
```

Why is it colPos = Array ?
Shouldn't it be a number instead of an array?

This is in my DynamicContent.typoscript file.

```
lib.dynamicContent = COA
lib.dynamicContent {
5 = LOAD_REGISTER
5 {
    colPos.cObject = TEXT
    colPos.cObject {
        field = colPos
        ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT
        ifEmpty.cObject {
            value.current = 1
            ifEmpty = 0
        }
    }
    pageUid.cObject = TEXT
    pageUid.cObject {
        field = pageUid
        ifEmpty.data = TSFE:id
    }
    contentFromPid.cObject = TEXT
    contentFromPid.cObject {
        data = DB:pages:{register:pageUid}:content_from_pid
        data.insertData = 1
    }
    wrap.cObject = TEXT
    wrap.cObject {
        field = wrap
    }
}
20 = CONTENT
20 {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
        orderBy = sorting
        where = {#colPos}={register:colPos}
        where.insertData = 1
        pidInList.data = register:pageUid
        pidInList.override.data = register:contentFromPid
    }
    stdWrap {
        dataWrap = {register:wrap}
        required = 1
    }
}
90 = RESTORE_REGISTER
}
```

If I change {register:colPos} to 0 for example, the site loads but then the layout is wrong. Can you explain me why I get this exception?

Comment: my second question (1st: what TYPO3 version?): why do you do it so complicated? instead of `registers`, you only use once, in a `select` you could use markers like shown in the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/latest/Functions/Select.html?highlight=select#markers)

Comment: @Bernd: Actually, the `lib.dynamicContent` solution makes column mapping easier, as you no longer need to take care of each column manually. Please see the new official [Site Package Tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SitePackageTutorial/ContentMapping/Index.html) (or my answer).

Answer (score 3):

## Rendering content in TYPO3

In one way or another, you'll have to map a backend column to Fluid (variable or viewhelper). For that, TypoScript is needed.

Previously, you had to write something like this in TypoScript (take note of the comments):

```
page = PAGE
page {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        // [...]

        variables {
            // Add new variable of type CONTENT.
            // 'colPos=0' selects all content in backend column with number '0':
            leftColumn = CONTENT
            leftColumn {
                table = tt_content
                select {
                    orderBy = sorting
                    where = colPos=0
                    where.insertData = 1
                }
            }

            // Copy configuration of the first variable,
            // but change the column number to '1':
            rightColumn < .leftColumn
            rightColumn.select.where = colPos=1
        }
    }
}
```

In the Fluid template, you then use this variables to render the content where it's needed (simplified):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">{leftColumn}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">{rightColumn}</div>
</div>
```

For every new column that you need, there had a new variable to be added in your TypoScript. Imagine a page layout with 15 columns in total: it's cumbersome to map all of these to Fluid.

---

### The new way: `lib.dynamicContent`

In order to prevent this, this TypoScript Helper was invented. It is part of the pretty new [TYPO3 Site Package Tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SitePackageTutorial/ContentMapping/Index.html). I assume you already read this tutorial, as your version of `lib.dynamicContent` is identical.

An extended version could also be found in the [bootstrap_package extension](https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/Configuration/TypoScript/Helper/DynamicContent.typoscript), which is also part of the official TYPO3 Introduction Package. I won't explain all its options here.

Therefore, I consider this solution as the current state of rendering columns in TYPO3.

#### What does it do?

In short, it basically does map content to your Fluid template, just like the `leftColumn = CONTENT` part shown above.
But it will save you the work of mapping all your columns manually, by using some TypoScript functions.

In your Fluid template, you'll then use the Fluid viewhelper `f:cObject`. This viewhelper provides a connection to TypoScript. With the `data` attribute you can pass values to this TypoScript. For the basic version of `lib.dynamicContent` you can pass the desired colPos number. Optionally, you could assign a different page ID than the current one. It will then be used by this TypoScript to dynamically build the select statement:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{colPos: '0'}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{colPos: '1'}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### Your specific case

To answer your initial question, we'll need some more information:

- Which TYPO3 version do you use?
- How did you try to render the content in the Fluid template? Did you only pass the `colPos` number in the data attribute?

I tried to reproduce your error message in TYPO3 v8 and v9 with different typing mistakes without any success. In all cases where I got an exception, the `colPos` part always contained the exact content of the data attribute, never `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using this in DynamicContent.typoscript

```
lib {
content {

    get < styles.content.get

    getLeft < .get
    getLeft {
        select.where = colPos=1
    }

    getRight < .get
    getRight {
        select.where = colPos=2
        slide = -1
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is the more _traditional_ solution, but no longer dynamic. As I now see that you use `slide` property: did you also try this with `lib.dynamicContent`? How did you use it? Please amend this information in your question. Also, see my answer.